# ¿Como filtrar distinct con Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Tengo esta consulta

```
Product.objects.filter().order_by('product_category', '-sum_sold').distinct('product_category')
```

tiene como objetivo mostrarme 1 producto por categoria y ordenarlos segun sus ventas

pero alfiltrar **distinct** tengo este error

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must
>   match initial ORDER BY expressions                LINE 1: SELECT
>   COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON

e estado probando se la siguiente manera

```
 Product.objects.all().annotate(Count('category',distinct=True))
```

pero me muestra todos los productos y solo me ordena por categoria

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698630/django-select-distinct

Comment: tambien lo tengo me sale el mismo error que coloco alli

Comment: Intenta la siguiente consulta: `Product.objects.filter().order_by('product_category', '-sum_sold').distinct('product_category', 'sum_sold')`, y dime si funciona.

Comment: no funciono de echo yo lo hice asi pero no me funciono pero hay me las apañe para hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

No puedo comentar intenta

```
 Product.objects.order_by('product_category', '-sum_sold').distinct('product_category')
```

Comment: No es exigencia amigo y créeme don fáciles de conseguir

Comment: Podría no ser un comentario si indicas por qué esto resolvería la pregunta.

Comment: mm sera que tengo que dedicarle tiempo al sitio. Y bueno el usa **filter** el propio error lo dice un filtro de tipo distinct **debe iniciar** con order_by no con el filter y no es necesario tampoco se supone que para eso esta el distinct para extraer elementos que no se repiten. **Ahora bien** si necesita solo uno puede usar **limit** para obtener el primer elemento distinto de la tabla
Ojala me haya explicado bien. saludos